# display progress bar in console while copying files. using tqdm in python

Tags: python, progress-bar, shutil, tqdm

I have a python script that read from source folder and copy existing files into the specified destination using shutil package.

I want to show a progress bar while copying these files so i tried to import tqdm package, but when i try to run the program it crash and display the below error:

> for obj in iterable : typeError: 'int' object is not iterable

## code:

```
#packages for list and copy folders & files.
import calendar
import os
import shutil
from os import path
from datetime import date

#packags for progressBar
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep


def main():
    copy("O:/PDF/")


dst3 = "C:/Users/gmatta/Documents"

def copy(src):
    src2 = os.path.join(src, datefile)
    z=0
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(src):           
        print(f'Found directory: {dirpath}')
        if len(dirnames)==0 and len(files)==0:
            print("this directory is empty")
            pass

        for  file in files:
            full_file_name = os.path.join(dirpath, file)

            if os.path.join(dirpath)== src2:
                if file.endswith("pdf"):
                    numfile = len(files)

# the problem is in the 2 lines below 
                    for z in enumerate(tqdm(numfile)):
                        sleep(.1)
            #       #copy files PDF TO dest 
                    shutil.copy(full_file_name, dst3)
                    z+=1
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: go to check what enumerate returns in python doc and you'll find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`tqdm` expects an iterable argument](https://tqdm.github.io/).

In this line in your code

```
for z in enumerate(tqdm(numfile)):
```

`numfile` is an integer. 
Try using `range(numfile)` perhaps?