# Progress bar when copying one large file in Python?

Tags: python, file-copying, tqdm

I want to use [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/) to display a progress bar when copying a single large file from one filepath to another.

This is not the same as [showing a progress bar when copying multiple small files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342365/display-progress-bar-in-console-while-copying-files-using-tqdm-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

Strategy:

1. [Determine the length of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283707/size-of-an-open-file-object) first so that you can tell tqdm what it is.
2. Normally then you'd use [shutil.copyfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) (or [shutil.copyfileobj](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj)) to actually copy the file but neither of those functions provide a way to receive updates during the copy, which we need to forward to tqdm:

   - So I created a slightly modified version of `copyfileobj` which supports passing an update function which is called regularly during copying.
   - Then I passed the tqdm's `update` method as the update function to the new `copyfileobj` so that it gets called regularly during the copy.

Code:

```py
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

def copy_with_progress(source_filepath, target_filepath):
    with open(source_filepath, 'rb') as source_file:
        with open(target_filepath, 'wb') as target_file:
            source_file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
            file_length = source_file.tell()
            
            print(f'Copying: {source_filepath} ({file_length:n} bytes)')
            source_file.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
            with tqdm(total=file_length, unit='B', unit_scale=True) as progress_bar:
                copyfileobj_with_progress(
                    source_file, target_file,
                    progress_func=progress_bar.update)

# Based on shutil.copyfileobj 
_WINDOWS = os.name == 'nt'
COPY_BUFSIZE = 1024 * 1024 if _WINDOWS else 64 * 1024
def copyfileobj_with_progress(fsrc, fdst, length=0, progress_func=None):
    if not length:
        length = COPY_BUFSIZE
    if progress_func is None:
        progress_func = lambda offset: None
    
    # Localize variable access to minimize overhead.
    fsrc_read = fsrc.read
    fdst_write = fdst.write
    
    while True:
        buf = fsrc_read(length)
        if not buf:
            break
        fdst_write(buf)
        progress_func(len(buf))  # delta offset
```

Comment: You could also directly retrieve the size with `os.stat()`, without needing to seek back and forth.

Comment: BTW, you might think about trying to correctly handle file-like objects that aren't seekable (which will be pretty much identical to the set for which stat won't give you a useful size -- FIFOs, many kinds of character devices, files in procfs, etc). Even if that just means falling back to a normal copy without a progress bar, it's better to gracefully degrade than fail outright.